# Kinvey URL REST GET request with related tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kinvey

So my problem is that i have 2 collections(tables) into my Kinvey App (Country and Town). 
The Country table has an added column("name").
The Town table has two columns("name", "country").

So i want my $.ajax request to return only the name of the towns who has a specific country.name choosed by the user.

For example if i have the rows into the Town table -->

```
{ name: "Manchester", country: (related to the row in Country table with name "England" ) }
{ name: "Liverpool", country: (related to the row in Country table with name "England" ) }
{name: "Berlin", country: (related to the row in Country table with name "Germany" )
```

And the client in my page type "England" into some input-text field, to list "Manchester" and "Liverpool".

How should the URL of my query look like ? Should i use ?resolve= or i should use ?query=   ?

I used this kind of JSON body for my POST request to add the relations between the tables -->

```
{
  "name": "Liverpool",
  "country": 
   {
     "_type" : "KinveyRef",
     "_id" : (Englands country row id),
     "_collection" : "Country" 
   } 
}
```

P.S. I prefer to use $.ajax.

Answer (score 0):

So, generally we wouldn't recommend using Kinvey in this way, because Kinvey is in no way a relational database.   Kinvey does support references and reference resolution, but doing so via REST is difficult compared to using one of our SDK's.

Beyond that, it is generally much more sensible to structure your data to conform to Mongo-style objects.   If you have a "Location" collection, just put all the information about a location in there and use your app logic to determine what bits of information you want to display.

Example:

Collection Locations:
{"Country":"United Kingdom", "City":"London", "Landmark Name": "Big Ben", "Latitude": 51.5008, "Longitude": 0.1247, "Comment": "You should see Big Ben around sunset, it's beautiful!"}

Using a structure where you have all the information in one place will reduce the overall amount of API calls you need to make, will ensure that you can easily update your objects (as we don't allow for partial object updates).  This will also make it easier for you to add / remove fields to an object, as they will all be central to that object.

Another example of this happened with someone who was making a restaurant review application and they said: "I have a table of restaurant ID's and what type they map to, a table of restaurants, and a table of scores broken down into type".   I suggested:  Why not turn that into a single collection, do away with the id's, make it a restaurant, with type, reviews, etc all in one collection.  When a new review is added, grab the affected restaurant object and add another review field to the json.

Thinking about things in terms of flat data does take some adjustment, but being able to change your schema in any way you want at any time makes development of new applications a lot faster since the whole "take a day or two to diagram your schema before you start" step out of things and allows you to start building and hash out the details as they become more clear.